# SQLite insert into table if the table is empty

Tags: sql, sqlite

First I created this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS template 
(
     tag TEXT, 
     link TEXT
)
```

Then I want to insert into the table if it's empty, I tried to use

```
INSERT INTO template 
    SELECT 'ggl', 'google.com' 
    FROM DUAL 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM template)
```

like people suggested in similar questions on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work for me, why?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: Remove `FROM DUAL`

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry I spelled it poorly, I've meant that it doesn't insert the items at all

Comment: @forpas Thanks, it is working properly now, can you post it as an answer and explain why ```DUAL``` didn't it work for me here?

Comment: Why did you add `FROM DUAL` in the first place? What is `DUAL`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Comment: SQLite does not support DUAL. There is no need for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `or ignore` phrase helped me with inserting values to a column only if it's empty:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table(column)
VALUES (value1), (value2)
```

It simply skips if the column is already populated with some entries.